# Valgrind memcheck error inside strchr function

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind reports the following memcheck error inside teh strchr function

```
==5801== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5801==    at 0x34BB32865A: __strchr_sse42 (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
```

I linked gdb to valgrind to possibly walk throught he strchr code, but I could not do that. All my local variables are initialized and the program works just fine. I do not understand where the valgrind error is coming from

```
bool 
Graph::CheckValues( cfgs_val_t & cfgs, const char * mval ) 
{ 

    int matched = 1, av = -1, ev = -1; char * mv, * p1, * p2, * p3, * fn, *                args; 
    cfgs_val_t::iterator iter; bool cfg_anyval = false;

    mv = strdup( mval );  
    p1 = mv;
    p2 = p1;
    for( ; ; )
    {
       if( *p2 == '=' )
       {
           *p2 = '\0';
            p3 = strchr( p1, '(' );  
            if( p3 != nullptr )
            {
                return true;
            }
     }
}
```

My code works just fine, other than the valgrind error

Comment: The valgrind error is reported in a few cases when this function is called. e.g. when the mval is "bypass=0" or "p.seq.sync_rst_en=1"

Comment: Your code snippet looks incomplete -- the number of `{` characters does not match the number of `}` characters. Also, shouldn't there be a `return false` somewhere?

Comment: Provide a complete example that can be run. That loop is very incomplete and is not functional. The Valgrind error possibly comes from looping past the end of the string,  but no way to know with that code.

Comment: I just presented a relevant portion of a large working function. The valgrind error shows as soon as it hits the line containing strchr

Comment: Well, I don't believe `strchr` itself is the problem, so without something people can actually run and then look at, hard to say what your uninitialised value is. It probably thinks that `p1` was never set, but that  `strdup` in your example code makes that appear to not be the case.